# How to read/edit a GUI/MFC application in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, automation, ironpython

I want to automate one of my tasks, by changing a third-party GUI/MFC application's properties as per my requirements. Every time I need to carry out any testing, I need to change the properties of the application to test my software.

I tried to automate it by using Python and IronPython. After Googling a lot I found IronPython, because the GUI is written C# and VB.NET.

Suppose when opening the GUI in its editor it gives me the option to edit the properties, MFC contains lots of controls.. e.g.:

```
Enter Time |__| //Need to enter the value in the box
Enter the dealy |__| //Need to enter the value in the box
Want to display |_| //Check box , check or uncheck
some Radio buttons.
Some more controls.
....
....
```

I want to control all the changes from my Python script. I will just enter the value from my script and it will update them in the GUI.

I wrote a script in IronPython to read the GUI:

```
fw = open("MyFile.vnb", 'r')
for line in fw.readlines():
    print (line)
```

I found plenty of encrypted/encoded characters along with some of the C#/VB.NET codes in the console. So, I am completely stuck here.

I would like to know can we edit a third-party GUI with Python/IronPython or not? Do I need to use some special tools from Python to edit the GUI?

Comment: This question needs significant clarification. Do you mean you want to pass different values into the program behind the GUI (in which case using the GUI at all may well be unnecessary)? Do you want to use Python to actually alter the code for the GUI, changing what it looks like when the program gets run? Why did you expect that opening the program file in Python would give you anything sensible?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I don't ant to open the gui, Like we do in C programming. Open a File write something to it. The file open behind the scene and writes the data into the file and make it ready for use. Like that, I don't want to open the file but I would like to run the script which will internally change the code of GUI.

Comment: its just binary ... all you have to do is open it in a hex editor and find the pattern that you need to change.... then you need to figure out what you need to change it to ... then you need to write a regex to do it in python.... you probably want to open the file with `rb` ...

Comment: That hasn't clarified anything for me, I'm afraid. Could you please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28073528/edit) to explain exactly what you're trying to achieve with all of this? If you just want to vary the parameters the GUI injects into whatever program it controls, you can probably bypass the GUI altogether.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Sorry for the typo, as my "w" key has some problem. Yes I dont want it appear on-sreen. I just gave an example of C language.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Sorry for my poor English. Yes you are right, I want to vary  the  papameters GUI injects into whatever program it control

Answer (score 0):

If you need classic GUI automation you can control MFC application by [pywinauto](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) library. You can send keyboard events, mouse clicks, moves etc. pywinauto has also limited support for .NET controls (simple automation like buttons, text boxes etc. is available). I guess this is realistic task (see sample video by the link above).

But if you need some binary instrumentation to change the GUI executable permanently (it sounds strange), this is completely another topic. Read about [PIN tool](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/65163/Pin/html/). It's used for profilers development, for example. Collecting stack samples, unwinding call stacks and other tricky reverse engineering things. :)

Comment: I think you understood, what exactly I am looking for. I think in `pywinauto` the applicaion will open and then I will send some keyboard or mouse events to get the things done. But I do not ant to open the application, I want everything will happen behind the scene (Like text box updation, automation of buttons). So is there any way to do it. I tried to see the application in Hex editor, I saw only the .NET codes with Hex values, which made me confuse to go ahead.Please guide me how can I proceed.